# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\ \sqrt[n]{c} = 1$ for $c>0$ directly by the definition of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How can I prove by definition (with $\epsilon$ and $N$) that, for $c>0$,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\ \sqrt[n]{c} = 1 ?$$

Thanks.

Comment: go buy a copy of Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis.  you wont regret it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume first $c>1$ and write $c^{1/n}=1+h_n$ with $h_n>0$. Taking $n$-th powers and using the binomial theorem get
$$
c=(1+h_n)^n=1+nh_n+\dots>1+nh_n\implies 0<h_n<\frac{c-1}{n}.
$$
Then
$$
0<c^{1/n}-1<\frac{c-1}{n}.
$$
You can use this inequality to apply the standard $\epsilon$-$N$ argument.

If $0<c<1$, use $c^{1/n}=1/(1/c)^{1/n}$.

Comment: You don't need the binomial theorem, just Bernoulli's inequality for integer exponents

Comment: I have edited my answer, but I think you need some kind of inequality before using epsilons.

Comment: Julian Thank you very much!

Comment: @kahen: Can you please explain me more about what to do when c<1? thanks

Comment: Can someone please post further elaboration when c<1. I've tried putting what Julian suggested in the inequality. I also tried saying that $c=(1+d)^n$ and using Bernoulli inequality

Comment: I am sure you know that if $a_n\to a\ne0$ then $1/a_n\to1/a$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\frac{\ln(c)}{n}\right)=\exp\left(\ln(c)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n}\right)=\dots$$

Comment: Jerry, your last two answers have been flagged by the software as low quality because you aren't using very many words. It would help if you added a little more explanation to them.

Comment: I would think any further elaboration would fall in the spoonfeeding realm, which I am told the majority of the users here frown upon.

Comment: The OP asked for a prove by definition. As I read it the answer should involve some $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: Well, when I answered, there was no indication he wanted an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. (He edited after I posted.) :P I'll delete this later.

Comment: @Jerry: who told you that? My impression is that people here generally prefer more exposition to less.

Comment: I won't reveal the identity of the guilty party, sorry. I was told by my acquaintance that people who give elaborate answers to homework get downvoted here, and since this seemed to be homework... anyway, I've my downvote, and I don't really care for reputation anyway (otherwise I'd register).

Comment: @jerry: I wrote "by defenition" before your answer and added the epsilon and N after, anyway I thank you for the answer, I belive you used here Continuity, right?

Comment: And thanks for the downvote @Nir. :) Julián gave you the machinery required for $\epsilon-\delta$, so you might want to accept that one.